# jquery pagination

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

We are using jquery for pagination. We are pulling millions of records from the database and then th jquery does the pagination on the front end. that is a very slow process. Can someone advice us of a solution in php and jquery where we pull 50 records at a time?
Thanks

Comment: Which jQuery table plugin are you using?

Comment: Ridiculous.  Millions of records being sent to the client? Dear g-d!

Comment: @JacobRelkin Give the guy a break! He said he wants to serve them 50 records at a time. That's only 20,000 pages to click through per million records!!! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use ajax instead of retrieving the whole thing, try this:

```
$.get("path/to/page.php", { param1: "myParam1", page: "pagenumber" },
   function(data){
   $('#datacontainer').html(data);
});
```

For further information on the `$.get` function read this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 6):

Do you really need/want to use jquery for the pagination aswell?

On the php side you can work out the row number to start from (using page_number-1 * number_of_rows_per_page) so page 1 will start at row 0, page 2 at 50. That way you only grab 50 rows at a time.

jQuery can then be used to style the table and or send an ajax request to the script to retrieve the specific rows.

```
$page_number = $_GET['page']; //Could POST this if u want to keep your urls tidy
$num_rows_per_page = 50;
$start_row = ($page_number -1) * $num_rows_per_page;

//This will get just the specified number of rows
$sql = "SELECT * from mytable LIMIT $start_row, $num_rows_per_page"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.net/download.aspx) for an ASP.NET MVC app but they do a php version which should be good to use.

Answer (score 0):

A simple jquery pagination for table, div and li you can see it from 
[Simple Jquery Pagination](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2MMQ6ojuFMHUUZGV2FKb0I3eTg&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

http://gloryplus.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=81&product_id=176

```
if ($page < $counter - 1) 
 $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next >></a>";
```